# Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized react native mapbox

Tags: react-native, mapbox

i am getting a authorization error when using mapbox in react native

[https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v1/navigation/android/maven/com/mapbox/navigation/ui/1.5.0/ui-1.5.0.pom'](https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v1/navigation/android/maven/com/mapbox/navigation/ui/1.5.0/ui-1.5.0.pom%27). Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

i am using the package ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/@homee/react-native-mapbox-navigation )

according package documentation i am doing the same.

my build.gradle file is

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
          maven {
          url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v1/navigation/android/maven'
          authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
          }
          credentials {
            username = "mapbox"
            password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: "" 
          }
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven {
          url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v1/navigation/android/maven'
          authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
          }
          credentials {
            username = "mapbox"
            password = project.properties['MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN'] ?: "" 
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your credentials is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar issue. My first advice would be that if you're using their public Access token, create a new one from [Access Tokens](https://account.mapbox.com/access-tokens) and make sure Downloads:Read scope is checked. Then create a gradle.properties file in "your_projects_directory.gradle" (which to me was C:\Users\USERNAME\AndroidStudioProjects\ .gradle), and paste the following line:

```
MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN=YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
```

You should replace YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY with your actual access key of course. Just in case Android Studio is unable to find this newly created gradle.properties file, I would recommend adding a duplicate of the above line to your project gradle.properties file [This was what fixed my issue] although I'm not sure if this has any security implications.
Then finally your build.gradle should contain this:

```
maven {
        url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
        authentication {
            basic(BasicAuthentication)
        }
        credentials {
            // Do not change the username below.
            // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
            username = 'mapbox'
            // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password
            password = System.getenv("MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN") ?: project.property("MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN") as String
        }
    }
```